# Texture.loadFromFile doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I am using SFML 2.2 and Visual Studio Express 2013.

I simply want to load a texture and apply it to a sprite just like it is done in the tutorials at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-sprite.php.

The problem is that texture.loadFromFile() doesn't work at all for me. I have tried to place my file in a thousand different places and I always get the same result. Finally I decided to use the full path, same problem. I also tried different formats: PNG, GIF, JPG, BMP. I also tried to save them with different software: Photoshop, GIMP, paint. Nothing helps. The only error message displayed is:

**Failed to load image "**

Exactly like that, only one double quote at the end.

Help!

Here's the minimal code I tried.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {    
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("C:\\temp.png"))
      return 1;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run as administrator? It might be that your program doesn't have access permissions for that file.

Comment: I tried running it as administrator but had the same problem. Thanks for the input anyway!

Comment: Put the file in the same directory as your source files, and just do `.loadFromFile("temp.png");`

Comment: I have tried that as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: @hme can you post the exact error message you get when loading fails? The above one seems truncated.

Comment: @Hiura that is the full error message, truncated and all.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the problem was.

I was running in debug mode but had configured the non-debug .lib files in the Linker under additional dependencies. Switching the configuration to Release suddenly made everything work.

To get the debug configuration to work, I just had to change the names from sfml-graphics.lib to sfml-graphics-d.lib (and so on). That did the trick!

Thanks everybody for the help!