# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime-error, sfml

Hi i am new to using SFML library, i want to show an image using SFML library but getting "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location" error on following code:
I have added the png file in the project location but still the code doesn't work

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::Texture t1;
    std::cout << "load enemy texture" << std::endl;
    //system("dir");

    if (!t1.loadFromFile("test.jpg")) {
        std::cout << "Could not load enemy texture" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    sf::Sprite enemySprite;
    enemySprite.setTexture(t1);
    enemySprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
     
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(enemySprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You are not including any SFML library. 2. You forgot the whitespace before `<iostream>` (sometimes that produces errors)

Comment: @Migue Thanks for your comment i have already added sfml library in the class but while adding question that part was not included due to not adding space. I have also done configuration according to sfml documentation

Comment: have you added the whitespace too?

Comment: @Miguel yes but the whitespace doesn't affect anything

Comment: Have you tried to run the debugger to see where does it crash?

Comment: @Miguel it crashes on the line where i try to load the .png file

Comment: Would this help? [Texture.loadFromFile doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289059/texture-loadfromfile-doesnt-work)

Comment: I've just tried the code (using an image of my own) and it works correctly, so it has to do with your image (if you are working on windows, make sure that you are seeing the whole name and not hiding the extension)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that did the trick, it was due to wrong libraries were imported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture.loadFromFile doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289059/texture-loadfromfile-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes it solved my question

Comment: When voting to close a question as duplicate this comment gets posted automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

as link suggested by @Yksisarvinen in the comment switching the configuration to Release suddenly made everything work.

To get the debug configuration to work, I just had to change the names from sfml-graphics.lib to sfml-graphics-d.lib (and so on).

Thank you guys.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.